# Coffescript closure _this reference lost within nested loops

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Here is sth interesting on CoffeeScript I observed.

**TLDR: {**

We know that the fat arrow (`=>`) generates a closure saving the reference to `this` and every reference of `@` would be substituted with the original value of `this`. Thus the following coffeescript code:

```
=>
  @sth
```

would produce the following:

```
(function(_this) {
  return (function() {
    return _this.sth;
  });
})(this);
```

Notice the `_this.sth`.

**}**

But here is the corner case I found:

```
=>
  for a in sth
    for b in @sth
      sth
```

Which evaluates to:

```
(function(_this) {
  return (function() {
    var a, b, i, len, results;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = sth.length; i < len; i++) {
      a = sth[i];
      results.push((function() {
        var j, len1, ref, results1;
        ref = this.sth;
        results1 = [];
        for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
          b = ref[j];
          results1.push(sth);
        }
        return results1;
      }).call(_this));
    }
    return results;
  });
})(this);
```

This is a bit long, but the problem is that the inner loop itterates through `this.sth` instead of `_this.sth`.

The exact lines of the inner loop are:

```
ref = this.sth;
results1 = [];
for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
  b = ref[j];
```

Is this the normal behaviour, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the inner loop more closely:

```
results.push((function() {
  var j, len1, ref, results1;
  ref = this.sth;
  // Loop stuff goes here...
}).call(_this));
```

The inner loop is wrapped in a function (as part of the loop comprehension code) which is evaluated using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

`call` is called with `_this` (the stashed/bound `@` from the `=>`) so `this` inside that function is actually `_this` and all is well.

If you suppress the comprehension code by explicitly returning nothing:

```
=>
  for a in sth
    for b in @sth
      sth
  return
```

then you'll see the `ref = _this.sth` that you were originally expecting:

```
(function(_this) {
  return (function() {
    var a, b, i, j, len, len1, ref;
    for (i = 0, len = sth.length; i < len; i++) {
      a = sth[i];
      ref = _this.sth; # <---------------------------
      for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
        b = ref[j];
        sth;
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```